# How to add a Q-Q plot in R Markdown?

Tags: r, r-markdown

I have set a linear model which I wish to create a qq plot for. I can do it in the standard R console by using `plot(mymodel)` and then hitting enter for a second time, but how can I produce this plot in Markdown?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Updated Answer

With `{ggfortify}`, `{ggplot2}` can now handle `lm` objects with `ggplot2::autoplot()` and produce the standard diagnostic plots. This might be another nice way to include regression diagnostics in your RMD. If, for example, you want just the qqplot you can specify `autoplot(which = 3)`.

```r
# load libraries
library(ggfortify)
#> Warning: package 'ggfortify' was built under R version 4.1.1
#> Loading required package: ggplot2
library(ggplot2) # loaded by ggfortify anyhow but included to be explicit

# simulate data
dat <- as.data.frame(rmultinom(2, 1000, 1:50))

# build linear model
mymodel <- lm(V1 ~ V2, data = dat)

# autoplot regression diagnostics
ggplot2::autoplot(mymodel)
```

[image]

```r
# autoplot just the qqplot
ggplot2::autoplot(mymodel, which = 3)
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2021-08-30 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>

### Original Answer

You need to explicitly access the residulas of your model with `rstandard(mymodel)` and then make a qqplot. Here's an example:

```r
# simulate some data
dat <- as.data.frame(rmultinom(2, 1000, 1:50))

# build linear model
mymodel <- lm(dat$V1 ~ dat$V2)

# make qqplot of residuals
qqnorm(residuals(mymodel))
```

Which gives you:

[image]